Where to start with this question?
How would I start in finding a solution?
I analyzed the circuit for A and C. The switch is at A-C, and the circuit is in steady-state. I calculated the inductor current and capacitor voltage, as these are the initial conditions.
I’m stuck on how to use the initial conditions (continuity of inductor current and capacitor voltage) to find the values at infinite amount of time. Could you guide me on applying them to complete the solution? I think I am making a mistake.
I found \$2+(t+2)e^{-2t}\$ but I think it is not correct.


I found 2+(t+2)e^-2t but I think it is not correct.

How are ωo=(LC)^-1, and ζ= R/(2*sqrt(L/C)) used to solve this in a differential equation.?

Welcome to [electronics.se]! However, there are several problems with your posts. 1. You need to [edit] your question with additional details rather than post comments on it. 2. Posting a new question rather than fixing a closed/deleted question (by editing it) will eventually result in a question ban for your account. 3. For homework questions like this you need to show your work (not just your result).

This 2nd order equation will have a product of a cos (t/Tau) and an exponent with a time constant with i(0)=4 settling to 2A

YOu can verify easily here, but you must learn the math of solving the 2nd order equation in terms of ωo and ζ  https://tinyurl.com/23czz3yl

Mods: Is this the best way you teach students how to learn by closing their ability to show their work??

The initial condition for  i  is staring right at you in your schematic: 4A.
Now, flip the switch. What happens next? To make it clearer (and save you some confusion), combine the 12V source, the 6Ω resistor, and the 3Ω resistor into a Norton equivalent. Then, go from there and finish your homework. You’re almost there!
